# ExtentsDrop running every 1 hour despite data being very fresh with one month retention

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a fresh Kusto database that I created yesterday itself with 30 days as retention policy , I haven't explicitly overridden retention policy for any of the tables. Whenever I issue `.show commands` , I see that the command of `CommandType` as `ExtentsDrop` is running every 1 hour with the command text as `.drop extents retention true older 720 hours from all tables` , I can understand that 720 hours is 30 days and in this case the command might not really be doing anything , but shouldn't Kusto run these drop commands only when extents go out of defined retention period ? Why is it unnecessarily running these commands even before retention period is hit? Kusto does have min/max timestamp stored for every extent , so it can trigger commands as and when required, I guess this is more of a design question as to how retention is implemented , but just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *... database ... with 30 days as retention policy, I haven't explicitly overridden retention policy for any of the tables.

- This means all tables in the database have an effective soft delete period of 30d.

---

> *... and in this case the command might not really be doing anything*

- Correct - if there are no extents to drop (e.g. cause none are older than 30d) - the `.drop extents` command doesn't drop anything.

---

> *shouldn't Kusto run these drop commands only when extents go out of defined retention period? ... I guess this is more of a design question as to how retention is implemented , but just curious.*

- The logic that decides which extents need to be dropped, according to the effective retention policies, is executed and enforced on the Data Engine service (which is the service you run `.show commands` against).
- As of this writing, that logic is triggered externally by the `.drop extents` command you referred to.

  - However, this isn't contractual and it's possible that in the future the same logic may be triggered differently.